# Shell script command

Tags: shell

In many shell scripts I am seeing `${#1}` in `if` condition..

I am unable to understand about this and what value it giving.

Can you please assist me and suggest few ebooks for shell script.

I am beginner of shell script.

Comment: `${#1}` is length of value represented by `$1`

Answer (score 0):

`${#1}` returns the length of the first positional parameter to the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 ${#1}
```

$ ./a bcde

prints: bcde 4

Answer (score 0):

`${#1}` is replaced with the length of the first parameter to the script. You can use this to test whether the parameter was specified at all (it will be 0 in this case), for example.

As for a tutorial, try these:

- [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)
- [BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)